# Using a dll in a Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store application in c# and I want to use a library to generate excel file within the application.
This one seems to be good to me: http://www.libxl.com

To use it I have:

- Added the dll as a file in the project.
- Setted the build action to "Content" and "copy to output directory" to always.

But when I try to use the library I keep getting a module not found error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any library you use must be included in the app package to be usable and meet the requirements of a Store app.  Which greatly restricts the kind of winapi calls code can make.  The odds that you can use this one are zero, +/- 1%

Answer (score 0):

You must not add the dll to your project. Instead rightclick on the references node in your Solution Explorer and then click Add Reference. This popups a dialog where you can selected multiple assemblies you can add. You then can click on browse and select your dll. After that you can use it in your project.

---

If you are generating a simple sheet. You could much easily generate a .csv file. On [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Export-To-CSV-Sample-b31b50cf) there is an example of this.

Comment: I've tried your first solution, but when deploying the application doesn't find the dll. I'm trying the csv option for the moment, but I'd prefer to make an excel file...